# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'threadsafe'

Tags: xml, thread-safety

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<appengine-web-app
    xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0
    http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.2.1/java/docs/appengine-web.xsd">

    <application>studio-101062123</application>
    <version>release4960</version>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/java/util/logging/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>

    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

</appengine-web-app>
```

why it give me the error like this

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'threadsafe'.

the same code had no error on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.2.1/java/docs/appengine-web.xsd, the `threadsafe` element isn't valid. Your other machine probably couldn't get this xsd or it doesn't validate the xml with the xsd.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of the appengine-api-sdk.

If you're using maven, and in my opinion you should be, use this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For viewers from the future, please refer to this page on the maven repo for the latest version (assuming 2.0 hasn't been created yet):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk

If that doesn't work, use this as the root-level tag in your appengine-web.xml:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0
    http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.9.13/java/docs/appengine-web.xsd">

        ...

</appengine-web-app>
```

Again, you may need to replace the "1.9.13" with latest version number.